# MVC business logic to access model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am currently working in ASP.NET MVC 4 while using the entity framework. I've never worked with MVC before, and have build a project with the following layers:

- GUI (Models,**Views, Controllers**,...)
- DAL (entity database and Repository + IRepository)
- BL (with my queries)
- COMMON
- WCF
- TESTING

Now, I'm trying to write a query in my BL which uses a model from my GUI-layer. As you can't simply reference to the GUI, I don't really know what to do here.

Here's the code from what I'm trying to to:

In my BL:

```
public static List<PSNAdres> GetAdres(IZoekRepository repo)
{
    List<PSNAdres> lijstTypes = (from t in repo.PSNAdres
                      select new PSNAdres {t.Gemeente, t.Straat, t.Postcode}).ToList(); 

    return lijstTypes;
}
```

**As I said: I am new to MVC. This layer-lay-out is what our MVC-specialist has told us to use as this is how he works.**

Comment: It might be worth checking your terminology here. The GUI should be dealing with 'Views' (or possibly view-models) but not models directly.

Comment: Generally speaking your BL (Domain) should be dealing with domain objects only. If you need GUI (View) Models make that conversion in the GUI layer (or a layer for that sole purpose).

Comment: Added some additional information regarding what my GUI has

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you ask for, but here is my answer. Simple scenario for presenting address list:

View models:

```
public class AddressListViewModel 
{
    public List<AddressViewModel> AddressList { get; set; }
    public bool CanAdd { get; set; }
}

public class AddressViewModel
{
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public bool CanEdit { get; set; }
    public bool CanDelete { get; set; }
}
```

BL:

```
public static List<Address> GetAddressList()//Doesn't take repository here, repositories are injected in constructor
{
    return adresRepo.PSNAdres.ToList(); 
}
```

Controller

```
public class AddressController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult List()
    {
        var addressList = blObject.GetAddressList();
        var model = new AddressListViewModel();
        model.AddressList = addressList.Select(a => 
            new AddressViewModel 
            {
                Country = a.Country.Name,
                City = a.City,
                Street = a.Street,
                CanDelete = ...check user access here...,
                CanEdit = ...check user access here...
            });

        model.CanAdd = ...check user access here...

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer here, but it's how I'm trying to work right now and it's giving me problems. The GUI,BL,DAL,... are all in different projects, but in thesame solution file. As referencing from the BL to the GUI isn't allowed, I'm looking for a way to fix it. Currently the BL (in the BL project) can't get to my PSNAdres Model (in the GUI) and I'm looking for a way to fix this.

Comment: @ThomasSchellekens: How can PSNAdres be in the GUI? Is PSNAdres representing database table or is it class created for presentation purposes. If first, it shouldn't be in GUI.

Comment: I get my database (view) in my DAL. Then i put it in a repository and go to my BL. There I try to use PSNAdres (model in GUI) which maps certain columns from my view to PSNAdres. I'm not sure on the terminoligy when it comes to MVC, so I hope I explained it correctly.

Comment: This isn't the best idea, you're populating the model in the controller, you should just instantiate the model in the controller and the model can populate itself (aka the thin controller, fat model approach)

Comment: @mattytommo: And the reason why this is not the best idea is?

Comment: @ThomasSchellekens: I am sorry, but I can't completely understand what you mean. You shouldn't get view in DAL. View layer get view model from controller. Controller uses BL layer. BL layer uses DAL layer.

Comment: You're fattening your controller with code that's populating the model, something that should be done in the model. Thin Controller, Fat Model is one of the MVC best practices :). Everything else is spot on though

Comment: @mattytommo: And this is one of the best practices because? You are writing what I should do, without any explanation. Controller does only mapping work, nothing else. Can you give me example of code, where I can see how it should be done? I surely shouldn't place object mapping and view models in BL layer, because view models are designed for specific GUI.

Comment: @LukLed I seem to have try and explain it a bit better. I have a solution with a DAL (database + repository). This goes to my BL-project in thesame solution where I have my query. I have my model currently in my GUI, but I'm probably going to move it to my COMMON layer as awrigley suggested.

Comment: Controllers are designed to route requests to methods, their purpose is to instantiate and return the model, *not populate* the model. If you change your List action methods to just create a new instance of the model, then populate the model in the constructor of the model.

Comment: @mattytommo: Can you give code example of what you are saying? Can you change my code to do it as you would like to see it?

Comment: @LukLed I can't edit your code, but everything in your list method starting with the line: `var model = ...` cut that into a constructor inside the `AddressListViewModel` class (obviously leave `return View(model)`) in the controller though :)

Comment: @ThomasSchellekens: View models shouldn't be accessible by BL layer, so you shouldn't place them in library, that is used by BL. They should be accessible to controller layer, because controller create view models and pass them to views. In my answer I assumed PSNAdres is DAL class.

Comment: @mattytommo: So are you saying, that ViewModel classes should take BL layer classes as parameters in constructor?

Comment: Well not exactly, just call the BL layer method from the model?

Comment: @mattytommo: I should probably move user access check to BL, because BL should work in user context and then use some DTOs and map them to view models. I know what you mean, but this answer was really not about how to create view model in controller, but BL should not access view model classes.

Comment: Yeah fair enough, I wasn't having a go was just trying to improve your answer :) good work though, comment this tomorrow to remind me on and I'll upvote you (i've reached the daily limit today, doh) :)

Comment: @LukLed I see there are some problems in understanding the structure of my project. The following image shows the structure that I'm using here with the relevant information (I think) http://imgur.com/TgaPS

Comment: @ThomasSchellekens: It still doesn't help me:) `MobileApp` should reference `MobileApp.BL`. `MobileApp.BL` should reference `MobileApp.DAL`. View models should reside in `MobileApp`.

Comment: @mattytommo: On the other side, I wouldn't want view model classes be aware of types returned by BL. That is why solutions like setting properties in controller or using AutoMapper come in mind.

Comment: @LukLed Hmmm true, depends on preference really, our viewmodels at work are actually in the BL layer (named Core), but that's our preference.

Comment: @LukLed I have always seen it as a very bad practice to reference to your bl-layer from your GUI. As I'm also using WCF (clients demand) it would really make it obsolete. I'm currently referencing from GUI to WCF which in turn goes to BL. I think I'll just try and use bring the Model to the COMMON-layer instead.

Comment: @ThomasSchellekens: `MobileApp` project is not GUI only. It contains controller layer, which references BL.

Answer (score 1):

Your GUI layer is just a consumer of functionality provided by the other layers.

As a result, your problem stems from having the model in there. If you are splitting your project into layers, you should move the model!

The default projects created by Visual Studio only have the model in the GUI layer for the case when people AREN'T going to split the GUI project into layers.  Ie, beginners.  It has nothing to do with the MVC approach.  As you are splitting the layers, you should move the model into a "Domain Layer" (see below).

**So, without further ado, move your models out of your GUI layer.**

A more practical approach than your design would be to follow the Domain design advocated by Steve Sanderson and Adam Freeman (Pro ASP.NET MVC 3.0 Framework, Apress [the book for version 4 isn't out yet]).  It is similar to your design, but more practical.  Without going into to much detail, in that approach, you separate the model and the buisness layer into a Domain project.  That gives you a much more practical design.

Unless you have specific requirements to do so, I think WCF is probably overkill too.  MVC is designed to provide a service oriented approach where you need it.

I would recommend reading the S Sanderson and A Freeman book.  It will spare you a lot of pain.